# Astyanax not respecting configured socket timeout

Tags: java, cassandra, timeout, astyanax

This is my setup:

- 4 nodes Cassandra 1.2.19
- Astyanax 1.56.49

I am setting configuration like

```
AstyanaxContext<Keyspace> context = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
    .forCluster(service.getClusterName())
    .forKeyspace(service.getKeySpaceName())
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()
         .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.NONE)
         .setCqlVersion("3.0.0")
         .setDefaultReadConsistencyLevel(consistencyLevel.getAstyanaxValue())
         .setDefaultWriteConsistencyLevel(consistencyLevel.getAstyanaxValue())
    )
    .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("b2bConnectionPool")
         .setPort(service.getPort())
         .setMaxConnsPerHost(5)
         .setSeeds(StringUtils.join(hosts, ","))
         // increase default timeout for heavy operations (milliseconds)
         .setSocketTimeout(15000)
         .setSSLConnectionContext(sslContext)
         .setAuthenticationCredentials(credentials)
    )
    .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor())
    .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());
```

Now there is a reproducible query that takes a long time and finally throws a `OperationTimeoutException`:

```
com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.OperationTimeoutException: OperationTimeoutException: [host=myhost(myip):13260, latency=10001(40007), attempts=4]TimedOutException()
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:171) ~[astyanax-thrift-1.56.49.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:65) ~[astyanax-thrift-1.56.49.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$1$2.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:190) ~[astyanax-thrift-1.56.49.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$1$2.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:182) ~[astyanax-thrift-1.56.49.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$ThriftConnection.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:151) ~[astyanax-thrift-1.56.49.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:119) ~[astyanax-core-1.56.49.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:338) ~[astyanax-core-1.56.49.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$1.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:180) ~[astyanax-thrift-1.56.49.jar:na]
```

The exception message says "latency=10001" and I thought this should be the socket timeout configured to 15000 ms but it's obviously not. How can I increase the timeout for a query operation in astyanax?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue with cqlsh but I could reproduce the query with a small java program. I will try out the config changes mentioned in the answers and give feedback afterwards.

Comment: Increasing the timeouts (see answers) did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the similar timeout exception when trying to query nodes with bigger data. I modified these 4 values in cassandra.yaml and it resolved all the timeout errors.

*How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete*
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 15000

*How long the coordinator should wait for seq or index scans to complete*
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 30000

*How long the coordinator should wait for writes to complete*
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 30000

*How long the coordinator should wait for counter writes to complete*
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 15000

Note: You need to do this in all the nodes in the cluster and also need to restart Cassandra in all of them.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are not encountering a socket timeout, rather an rpc timeout which i think cannot be controlled through Astyanax. In your stack trace, the exception wrapped inside `OperationTimeoutException` is `TimedOutException` which is thrown when an rpc timeout occurs (default 10 seconds). In case of a socket timeout, the `SocketTimeoutException` will be thrown.

Try executing your query with cqlsh and you will get a `Request did not complete within rpc_timeout` message.

Inside your `<cassandra_home>/conf/cassandra.yaml` try setting:

```
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 20000
rpc_timeout_in_ms: 20000
```

Restart your server and try the query execution again.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I will try it.